# How "reverse-encode" data in base58?

Tags: c#, algorithm, encoding, base64

I want to do a "reverse encoding" of data in base58. What I mean by reverse encoding is given an arbritrary base58 confirming string, I want to know the bytes that I could encode to reproduce that string. I would not necessarily have the entire base58 string though. I might just need to produce a base58 encoded string that only has a phrase or a word or some such

The same problem could be applied to base64 or any other encoding such as simple hex encoding.. I'm just not really sure how to approach the problem coming from the opposite angle as usual.

My application specifically has the additional complication (bitcoin addresses) that I need to have the data prefixed with 1 byte of arbitrary value, and then postfixed with 4 bytes of fairly arbritrary value(a checksum)

Although pseudo code of course would work, I'm specifically writing this in C#

Comment: you want a way to get the input back from the output of a generic algorithm? ... Brute Force (*try all inputs, use your algorithm, return the first input that matches*) ...

Comment: for just Base58 there seem to be some implementations - this is one using PHP a simple web search found me: https://www.darklaunch.com/2009/08/07/base58-encode-and-decode-using-php-with-example-base58-encode-base58-decode